# Update field if is null in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I need to update a field of a Document if such field is `None`, but I don't want to overwrite it if such field has a value.

Right now I'm doing the following:

```py
p = Person.objects(name="Foo").first()
if p.address is None:
    p.update(set__address="Bar Street, NY")
```

but it's not an atomic operation.

What I would like to do is something like:

```py
Person.objects(name="Foo").update_one(set__address_if_none="Bar Street, NY")
```

but I can't seem to find anything about it on the web.

Is there anything like this, or a different way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Person.objects(name="Foo", address=None).update(set__address="Bar Street, NY")
```

Although as far as I'm aware this **is not** atomic as well. I mean it is atomic on a single document, but not on the collection. To be truely atomic you would need a transaction which [Mongo seems to support now](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/).

Comment: Yes, I need it to be atomic on the collection. I will use transactions then.